# diff tool whith PDF generation option

Tags: windows, pdf, git, diff

I'm looking for a file comparison tool with the following criteria:

- Can be used in MS Windows
- Can be used with git (diff)
- Can be used from the command-line
- Can export comparison results to PDF

Comment: What sort of output are you expecting in your PDF? git diff (patch) type output?

Comment: I would prefer something side-by-side, such as Meld, WinMerge, or TortoiseMerge, whose results could be printed (I haven't seen one yet with a printing option) or exported to a printable formart (PDF, XPS, RTF, etc.).